# Custom >NAME group for components in EAGLE

Tags: schematics, eaglecad

I'm designing custom component library for my project and I'd like to create custom naming subset for my custom parts.

When ever I create custom part the default naming order is U$1, U$2 etc., when I add them to my projects later on. I'd like some custom part types to be listed as E1, E2, ... or some along with other resistors like R1, R2, etc. How to configurate parts in my custom library to belong to some specific letter group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are editing your device in your library, there is a prefix on the bottom right of the page.  This is where use choose it the device will be E1, E2, etc or R1, R2, etc.. or something else of your choosing.

For example, here's a screen shot of a simple button switch in my library that I have given a prefix of "S" so when I add them to my projects they are S1, S2, etc..

[image: Library editor in Eagle with Prefix shown in bottom right]